# LC3 Programming - Printing a histogram

Tags: lc3

I have to print a list similar to the one below where the @ bin is for all non alphabetical characters and there are bins for each alphabetical character. I need to have both capital and lowercase letters fall into the same bin. I have already developed working code to go through the string of words or characters. I am not sure where to start on this second part of the code though. This is in [LC-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC-3). Thanks in advance.

@ 000F

A 0002

B 0001

C 0004

D 0002

E 0005

Comment: How is this an electronics question?

Comment: I think this is more suitable for Stack Overflow.